# How to run wear app on real device

Tags: android, wear-os

How do I run my wear application on a physical Android Wear Smartwatch? I turned on USB debugging on both devices and also enabled the `debugging over bluetooth` option in the android wear companion app like the [official Google Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) says. But I cant see my Target device as connected.

EDIT: I solved the problem. First, I used a outdated ADB version. You need at least 1.0.31 to use debugging over bluetooth.
Second: there are two options in the smartwatches developer options. Enable debugging and enable debugging oder bluetooth. You need to enable booth.

Comment: you can sync your app from handheld device  to wear using 
Android Wear - Smartwatch app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app&hl=en

Comment: the complete instructions can be found on the official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*please use a decent search engine...

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

Comment: I get the "error: device offline" `message after using adb connect localhost:4444`

Comment: I used every walkthrough that I could find -.- reinstalled drivers. delete the adb_keys etc

Comment: I solved it. The debugging over bluetooth option wasnt enabled at the moto360. I just saw the debugging option.

Comment: Please give an answer to your own question, or edit your post if you can.